# Mosquitto bridged with RabbitMQ only retains the first message

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm currently using RabittMQ with the MQTT-plugin to support MQTT to my IoT devices. But I've also created a MQTT-bridge with mosquitto, but in the last 2-3 months I've seen some caching problems with retained messages published from RabbitMQ. The problem has probably been existing for a long time, but I just noticed this.
When the mosquitto-bridge starts up, it will receive messages on the topics it subscribes on. If the message is set to retained, it will only remember the first message it receives, the rest that follows gets ignored. 
I've tried to bridge with a mosquitto-instance, and I don't get this side-effect. It overwrites the retained message when a new message is received (as it should).

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

RabbitMQ version: 3.7.5

Mosquitto version: 1.4.15

Comment: Have you considered writing your mosquitto data to a database upon arrival then purging it once recorded?

Comment: I can confirm that we are seeing this same issue with mosquitto 1.6.7 and HiveMQ.